# Setting up pycharm python interpreter with a conda Enviroment

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, anaconda

I succesfully set up a virtual enviroment in Conda using `conda create -n tensor python=3.7` then I installed tensorflow and keras. Now when I try to use the python interpreter by going to add python interpreter then I click on conda.Then I click on Existing enviroment but when I go to select the actuall enterpreter (pythonw.exe) I cant find it where it should be.

Comment: What OS do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you activate the tensor environment you created, then typing python will use the Python 3.7 version that was defined in your statement. If you wish to use another version, just create a new virtual environment and use another version of python.